# Can I use a power cord with lower input amperage?

Tags: hard-drive

My hard drive power cord recently broke (power to wall, with a different cord for USB), and I found one from an older version of the device that I'm thinking about using to replace it. It has most of the same specs, although the input Max amerage is different. Is it safe to use on my hard drive and computer or is it best to buy a straight replacement? I had a quick look online and the max amperage isn't listed, so I'm not sure how important it is. I don't know much about what the specs mean, so any help is much appreciated.

**Original specs:**

> Input: 100-240V~50/60Hz Max. **0.6A** 
>   Output: 12V - 1.5 A

**Replacement specs:**

> Input: 100-240V-, 50/60Hz, **0.5A** Max. 
>   Output: 12V - 1.5 A

[Broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMb58.jpg)
[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmO16.jpg)
[Combined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tecUb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Input doesn’t matter unless we consider when you travel to another country.

The output rating, jack style, and polarity is what is important.

The output rating is sufficient. It should be the same voltage and it should be the same or greater amperage.

What you didn’t share with us is the polarity. Most, but not all power adapters indicate what is positive or negative. Almost universally, the sleeve or outside of the jack is negative and the inside is positive.

So, if the jack fits, there is little chance of going wrong.

Comment: If you're not 100% sure about the polarity, don't try, you may fry your drive.   The jack fitting means jack censored.

Comment: Both have the Center positive symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replacement with 0.5 amps fine.  The maximum wattage is 18 watts (ie 12volts x 1.5amps), and an input can support a much greater wattage of 50 watts and up (100volts x 0.5 amps)

The posters talking about polarity can be ignored, as polarity only applies to DC, not AC.

It's unclear from your post if the cable you are talking about is the cable from the wall into the power supply (which I am guessing is the case) - in which case you don't need to worry about polarity as it's AC, or if what you are looking at is a "cable" which includes PSU, in which case @appleoddity comments about jacks and polarity should be considered.  Why not post a link to the cable you are looking at so we can get a clearer picture?

Comment: Hi @Davidgo, yes the cable is from the wall into the hard drive. I've added some pictures to the original post.

Comment: Yes, these units are functionally identical.   They are both "centre positive" (ie the polarity is the same).  Its probable that the newer one is slightly more efficient, hence the lower input current number.